# Internet not working on ubuntu

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ipv6

I have seen the other similar issues but none of the posted solutions are working for me.

I recently upgraded a bunch of packages. I am dual booting ubuntu and windows.

IPv6 works. IPv4 gets an IP assigned. My router is set to give my machine a static IP. When I ping through IPv4 the domain is resolved, ping goes out but nothing comes in.

Connected via ethernet. All settings set to automatic.

Sorry for lack of pasted logs, can't access this website from that machine. Here's a link to a paste bin: https://pastebin.com/GFxq2Wnd

Edit: Upgraded from Ubuntu 20 to Ubuntu 22, the problem persists. I now get "temporary failure in name resolution" (v4 and v6), despite setting google as the DNS server for IPv4. Now both ipv4 and ipv6 don't work. Note during the upgrade process due to IPv4 failure, Firefox was not installed.

Contents of `resolve.conf`:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search hsd1.wa.comcast.net
```

Answer (score 0):

An old installation of wireguard was screwing up the connection. Deleted using `sudo nmcli connection show`.